# how to merge pull request without write permission on github?

Tags: github

I would like to know how to allow only assignee to merge pull request in GitHub but not participants.
i have provided to multiple assignee request to different scenario as read only , write permission but i'm looking as only have user merge pull request not write permission as same user?

Comment: **Please let me know i'm just stuck as per user permission now.**

Answer (score 0):

You must have permission, then you can action.

https://help.github.com/en/articles/permission-levels-for-a-user-account-repository#collaborator-access-on-a-repository-owned-by-a-user-account

Comment: Thanks for your effort but it is known to me but I wanna just created a new custom permission as only assigne have merged pull request but can not be able write